# Unity launchers and bar disappeared and unity --reset shows an error

Tags: 12.04, unity

I am having a problem with unity. I have launched Movie player with QNapi (application for downloading movie subtitles) and somehow Unity crashed and disappeared leaving just the opened windows without the launchers, title bars and unity's top bar.

[image]

After I go to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and try to `unity --reset` I get this error

```
unity-panel-service: no process found
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1600004

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x3a000c7

Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing session options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing scale options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done

(compiz:27639): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed
ERROR 2012-09-03 19:04:45 unity.launcher.trashlaunchericon TrashLauncherIcon.cpp:62 Could not create file monitor for trash uri: Operation not supported
Initializing unityshell options...done
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x2a0009f!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x2a000a2!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x2a000a2!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
WARNING: Unity currently default profile, so switching to metacity while resetting the values
```

What can I do (besides reboot) ?

**EDIT**

Launching `Unity Panel` from compiz didn't help either.